# Have to reload the app, when the button was clicked to see changes (Flutter)

Tags: http, flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

This is my project: https://github.com/OstapFilipenko/Picslash

I trying to create an app, that is getting pictures from the unsplash API and display those pictures.
First am calling an async function to get all images and to save them in List. I am using ListView.builder to display them, and on the end of the listView i have a Button that makes a API call and adding new Pictures to ListView.

The function:

```
var newImages = new List<Picture>();
  _getNewPics() async{
  counter++;
  newImages.clear();
  newImages = await API_connection(counter).getPictures();
  allImages.addAll(newImages);
}
```

And here is the button:

```
child: FlatButton(
              child: Text("Load More",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white
                      )
                    ),
              onPressed: (){
                _getNewPics();
              },
          ),
```

The problem is, that when I start the app nothing is displayed, so I have to ctrl+S (reload the app) and then I see images, the same i have to do when I click on "Load more" button.

It would be great, if somebody would help me:)

Comment: You prob need too put your get New images method in initstate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setState()` with `StatefulWidget` to rebuild the widget once the new images come.

Answer (score 0):

In java, you have a function called notifyDataSetChanged() which basically tells a listView that the list it is showing has changed and needs to be updated. Here is a detailed answer for Flutter to achieve the same - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619480/what-is-the-equivalent-code-in-flutter-for-madapter-notifydatasetchanged)

Answer (score 0):

Use the library flutter_phoenix for this.

```
void main() {
      runApp(
        Phoenix(
          child: App(),
        ),
      );
    }
```

if you want to restart your app just do this:

```
   IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  Phoenix.rebirth(context); },


icon: Icon(Icons.notes),
```